# SQL Server disconnect if response exceeds 1192 bytes

Tags: sql-server, tcp

Since few days now I had a strange problem with SQL Server (version 2012)
The engine is installed on a remote server.
The error that occurs when running a query is "TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known"
After several attempts I found that the error only occurs if the result size exceeds 1192 bytes.
In fact I tried with this select

```
SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(myField)) FROM  myTable WHERE id<16 --1192
SELECT myField FROM myTable WHERE id<16
```

The above query runs OK.
If I add a character to myField and I run the same query got the error

```
SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(myField)) FROM  myTable WHERE id<16 --1193
SELECT myField FROM myTable WHERE id<16
```

If I try the second query using Management Studio directly on server it runs witout problem

Comment: What client are you using?  What Service Pack and CU is the server on?

Comment: Does this also happen with a single row and varchar size of 1193?

Comment: I use SQL Server Management Studio, but i got the same problem with a c# connection. 
The error happens with any number of rows. if the sum of datalength is greater than 1193 bytes.

Comment: The servers has Windows Server 2012 R2 installed and SQL Server version 11.0.6251

Comment: There's a newer version SP4 you could update to, although it's probably unlikely to be SQL Server itself

Comment: So it works when run directly on the server but not when run remotely across the network? What's different between the two? Seems like you have network problems.

Comment: At a completely wild guess: perhaps MTU/MRU issues? Speak to network team